# How do I make images appear/disappear in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a battleship-type game. I am using `.blit` to display images that I load using the function `pygame.image.load`. I was wondering, is it possible to make images like this appear/disappear at different points?

My code is as follows:

```
import random, sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Set variables, like screen width and height
# globals
FPS = 60 #Determines the number of frames per second
REVEALSPEED = 2 #Determines the speed at which the squares reveals after being clicked
WINDOWWIDTH = 800 #Width of game window
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600 #Height of game window
TILESIZE = 40 #Size of the squares in each grid(tile)
MARKERSIZE = 40 #Size of the box which contatins the number that indicates how many ships in this row/col
BUTTONHEIGHT = 20 #Height of a standard button
BUTTONWIDTH = 40 #Width of a standard button
TEXT_HEIGHT = 25 #Size of the text
TEXT_LEFT_POSN = 10 #Where the text will be positioned
BOARDWIDTH = 6 #Number of grids horizontally
BOARDHEIGHT = 6 #Number of grids vertically
DISPLAYWIDTH = 200 #Width of the game board
EXPLOSIONSPEED = 10 #How fast the explosion graphics will play

XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (BOARDWIDTH * TILESIZE) - DISPLAYWIDTH - MARKERSIZE) / 2) #x-position of the top left corner of board
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (BOARDHEIGHT * TILESIZE) - MARKERSIZE) / 2) #y-position of the top left corner of board

#Colours which will be used by the game
BLACK   = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE   = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN   = (  0, 204,   0)
GRAY    = ( 60,  60,  60)
BLUE    = (  0,  50, 255)
YELLOW  = (255, 255,   0)
DARKGRAY =( 40,  40,  40)
transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)


#Determine what to colour each element of the game
BGCOLOR = GRAY
BUTTONCOLOR = GREEN
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
TILECOLOR = GREEN
BORDERCOLOR = BLUE
TEXTSHADOWCOLOR = BLUE
SHIPCOLOR = YELLOW
HIGHLIGHTCOLOR = BLUE


def main():
    """
    The main function intializes the variables which will be used by the game.
    """
    global DISPLAYSURF, FPSCLOCK, BASICFONT, HELP_SURF, HELP_RECT, NEW_SURF, \
           NEW_RECT, SHOTS_SURF, SHOTS_RECT, BIGFONT, COUNTER_SURF, \
           COUNTER_RECT, HBUTTON_SURF, EXPLOSION_IMAGES
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    #Fonts used by the game
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    BIGFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)

    # Create and label the buttons
    HELP_SURF = BASICFONT.render("HELP", True, WHITE)
    HELP_RECT = HELP_SURF.get_rect()
    HELP_RECT.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 180, WINDOWHEIGHT - 350)
    NEW_SURF = BASICFONT.render("NEW GAME", True, WHITE)
    NEW_RECT = NEW_SURF.get_rect()
    NEW_RECT.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 200)

    # The 'Shots:' label at the top
    SHOTS_SURF = BASICFONT.render("Shots: ", True, WHITE)
    SHOTS_RECT = SHOTS_SURF.get_rect()
    SHOTS_RECT.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 750, WINDOWHEIGHT - 570)

    # Load the explosion graphics from the /img folder
    EXPLOSION_IMAGES = [
        pygame.image.load("blowup1.png"), pygame.image.load("blowup2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("blowup3.png"),pygame.image.load("blowup4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("blowup5.png"),pygame.image.load("blowup6.png")]



    # Set the title in the menu bar to 'Battleship'
    pygame.display.set_caption('Battleship')

    # Keep the game running at all times
    while True:
        shots_taken = run_game() #Run the game until it stops and save the result in shots_taken
        show_gameover_screen(shots_taken) #Display a gameover screen by passing in shots_taken


def run_game():
    greenButton = pygame.image.load('green-button-icon-png-13.png')
    greenButton = pygame.transform.scale(greenButton, (75,75))
    rect = greenButton.get_rect()
    rect = rect.move((150, 475))

    redButton = pygame.image.load('red-button-1426817_960_720.png')
    redButton = pygame.transform.scale(redButton, (85,85))
    rect2 = redButton.get_rect()
    rect2 = rect2.move((400, 475))
    """
    Function is executed while a game is running.

    returns the amount of shots taken
    """
    revealed_tiles = generate_default_tiles(False) #Contains the list of the tiles revealed by user
    # main board object,
    main_board = generate_default_tiles(None) #Contains the list of the ships which exists on board
    ship_objs = ['raft'] # List of the ships available
    main_board = add_ships_to_board(main_board, ship_objs) #call add_ships_to_board to add the list of ships to the main_board
    mousex, mousey = 0, 0 #location of mouse
    counter = [] #counter to track number of shots fired


    while True:
        # counter display (it needs to be here in order to refresh it)
        COUNTER_SURF = BASICFONT.render(str(len(counter)), True, WHITE)
        COUNTER_RECT = SHOTS_SURF.get_rect()
        COUNTER_RECT.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 680, WINDOWHEIGHT - 570)

        # Fill background
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

        # draw the buttons
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(HELP_SURF, HELP_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(SHOTS_SURF, SHOTS_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(COUNTER_SURF, COUNTER_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(greenButton, rect)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(redButton, rect2)
        greenButton.fill(transparent)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(greenButton, rect)
        # Draw the tiles onto the board and their respective markers
        draw_board(main_board, revealed_tiles)


        mouse_clicked = False

        check_for_quit()
        #Check for pygame events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if HELP_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos): #if the help button is clicked on
                    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
                    show_help_screen() #Show the help screen
                elif NEW_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos): #if the new game button is clicked on
                    main() #goto main, which resets the game
                else: #otherwise
                    mousex, mousey = event.pos #set mouse positions to the new position
                    mouse_clicked = True #mouse is clicked but not on a button
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION: #Detected mouse motion
                mousex, mousey = event.pos #set mouse positions to the new position

        #Check if the mouse is clicked at a position with a ship piece
        tilex, tiley = get_tile_at_pixel(mousex, mousey)
        if tilex != None and tiley != None:
            if not revealed_tiles[tilex][tiley]: #if the tile the mouse is on is not revealed
                draw_highlight_tile(tilex, tiley) # draws the hovering highlight over the tile
            if not revealed_tiles[tilex][tiley] and mouse_clicked: #if the mouse is clicked on the not revealed tile
                reveal_tile_animation(main_board, [(tilex, tiley)])
                revealed_tiles[tilex][tiley] = True #set the tile to now be revealed
                if check_revealed_tile(main_board, [(tilex, tiley)]): # if the clicked position contains a ship piece
                    left, top = left_top_coords_tile(tilex, tiley)
                    blowup_animation((left, top))
                    if check_for_win(main_board, revealed_tiles): # check for a win
                        counter.append((tilex, tiley))
                        return len(counter) # return the amount of shots taken
                counter.append((tilex, tiley))

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def generate_default_tiles(default_value):
    """
    Function generates a list of 10 x 10 tiles. The list will contain tuples
    ('shipName', boolShot) set to their (default_value).

    default_value -> boolean which tells what the value to set to
    returns the list of tuples
    """
    default_tiles = [[default_value]*BOARDHEIGHT for i in range(BOARDWIDTH)]

    return default_tiles


def blowup_animation(coord):

    """
    Function creates the explosition played if a ship is shot.

    coord -> tuple of tile coords to apply the blowup animation
    """
    for image in EXPLOSION_IMAGES: # go through the list of images in the list of pictures and play them in sequence
        #Determine the location and size to display the image

        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (TILESIZE+10, TILESIZE+10))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(image, coord)
        pygame.display.flip()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(EXPLOSIONSPEED) #Determine the delay to play the image with


def check_revealed_tile(board, tile):
    """
    Function checks if a tile location contains a ship piece.

    board -> the tiled board either a ship piece or none
    tile -> location of tile
    returns True if ship piece exists at tile location
    """
    return board[tile[0][0]][tile[0][1]] != None


def reveal_tile_animation(board, tile_to_reveal):
    """
    Function creates an animation which plays when the mouse is clicked on a tile, and whatever is
    behind the tile needs to be revealed.

    board -> list of board tile tuples ('shipName', boolShot)
    tile_to_reveal -> tuple of tile coords to apply the reveal animation to
    """
    for coverage in range(TILESIZE, (-REVEALSPEED) - 1, -REVEALSPEED): #Plays animation based on reveal speed
        draw_tile_covers(board, tile_to_reveal, coverage)


def draw_tile_covers(board, tile, coverage):
    """
    Function draws the tiles according to a set of variables.

    board -> list; of board tiles
    tile -> tuple; of tile coords to reveal
    coverage -> int; amount of the tile that is covered
    """
    left, top = left_top_coords_tile(tile[0][0], tile[0][1])
    if check_revealed_tile(board, tile):
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, SHIPCOLOR, (left, top, TILESIZE,
                                                  TILESIZE))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top, TILESIZE,
                                                TILESIZE))
    if coverage > 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, TILECOLOR, (left, top, coverage,
                                                  TILESIZE))

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def check_for_quit():
    """
    Function checks if the user has attempted to quit the game.
    """
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


def check_for_win(board, revealed):
    """
    Function checks if the current board state is a winning state.

    board -> the board which contains the ship pieces
    revealed -> list of revealed tiles
    returns True if all the ships are revealed
    """
    for tilex in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for tiley in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            if board[tilex][tiley] != None and not revealed[tilex][tiley]: # check if every board with a ship is revealed, return false if not
                return False
    return True


def draw_board(board, revealed):
    """
    Function draws the game board.

    board -> list of board tiles
    revealed -> list of revealed tiles
    """
    #draws the grids depending on its state
    for tilex in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for tiley in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left, top = left_top_coords_tile(tilex, tiley)
            if not revealed[tilex][tiley]:
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, TILECOLOR, (left, top, TILESIZE,
                                                          TILESIZE))
            else:
                if board[tilex][tiley] != None:
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, SHIPCOLOR, (left, top,
                                     TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top,
                                     TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    #draws the horizontal lines
    for x in range(0, (BOARDWIDTH + 1) * TILESIZE, TILESIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x + XMARGIN + MARKERSIZE,
            YMARGIN + MARKERSIZE), (x + XMARGIN + MARKERSIZE,
            WINDOWHEIGHT - YMARGIN))
    #draws the vertical lines
    for y in range(0, (BOARDHEIGHT + 1) * TILESIZE, TILESIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (XMARGIN + MARKERSIZE, y +
            YMARGIN + MARKERSIZE), (WINDOWWIDTH - (DISPLAYWIDTH + MARKERSIZE *
            2), y + YMARGIN + MARKERSIZE))




def add_ships_to_board(board, ships):
    """
    Function goes through a list of ships and add them randomly into a board.

    board -> list of board tiles
    ships -> list of ships to place on board
    returns list of board tiles with ships placed on certain tiles
    """
    new_board = board[:]
    ship_length = 0
    for ship in ships: #go through each ship declared in the list
        #Randomly find a valid position that fits the ship
        valid_ship_position = False
        while not valid_ship_position:
            xStartpos = random.randint(0, (BOARDHEIGHT-1))
            yStartpos = random.randint(0, (BOARDHEIGHT-1))
            isHorizontal = random.randint(0, 1) #vertical or horizontal positioning
            #Type of ship and their respective length
            if 'battleship' in ship:
                ship_length = 5
            elif 'destroyer' in ship:
                ship_length = 4
            elif 'cruiser'in ship:
                ship_length = 3
            elif 'submarine' in ship:
                ship_length = 2
            elif 'raft' in ship:
                ship_length = 1

            #check if position is valid
            valid_ship_position, ship_coords = make_ship_position(new_board,
                xStartpos, yStartpos, isHorizontal, ship_length, ship)
            #add the ship if it is valid
            if valid_ship_position:
                for coord in ship_coords:
                    new_board[coord[0]][coord[1]] = ship
    return new_board


def make_ship_position(board, xPos, yPos, isHorizontal, length, ship):
    """
    Function makes a ship on a board given a set of variables

    board -> list of board tiles
    xPos -> x-coordinate of first ship piece
    yPos -> y-coordinate of first ship piece
    isHorizontal -> True if ship is horizontal
    length -> length of ship
    returns tuple: True if ship position is valid and list ship coordinates
    """
    ship_coordinates = [] #the coordinates the ship will occupy
    if isHorizontal:
        for i in range(length):
            if (i+xPos > (BOARDHEIGHT-1)) or (board[i+xPos][yPos] != None) or \
                hasAdjacent(board, i+xPos, yPos, ship): #if the ship goes out of bound, hits another ship, or is adjacent to another ship
                return (False, ship_coordinates) #then return false
            else:
                ship_coordinates.append((i+xPos, yPos))
    else:
        for i in range(length):
            if (i+yPos > (BOARDHEIGHT-1)) or (board[xPos][i+yPos] != None) or \
                hasAdjacent(board, xPos, i+yPos, ship): #if the ship goes out of bound, hits another ship, or is adjacent to another ship
                return (False, ship_coordinates) #then return false
            else:
                ship_coordinates.append((xPos, i+yPos))
    return (True, ship_coordinates) #ship is successfully added


def hasAdjacent(board, xPos, yPos, ship):
    """
    Funtion checks if a ship has adjacent ships

    board -> list of board tiles
    xPos -> x-coordinate of first ship piece
    yPos -> y-coordinate of first ship piece
    ship -> the ship being checked for adjacency
    returns true if there are adjacent ships and false if there are no adjacent ships
    """
    for x in range(xPos-1,xPos+2):
        for y in range(yPos-1,yPos+2):
            if (x in range (BOARDHEIGHT)) and (y in range (BOARDHEIGHT)) and \
                (board[x][y] not in (ship, None)):
                return True
    return False


def left_top_coords_tile(tilex, tiley):
    """
    Function calculates and returns the pixel of the tile in the top left corner

    tilex -> int; x position of tile
    tiley -> int; y position of tile
    returns tuple (int, int) which indicates top-left pixel coordinates of tile
    """
    left = tilex * TILESIZE + XMARGIN + MARKERSIZE
    top = tiley * TILESIZE + YMARGIN + MARKERSIZE
    return (left, top)


def get_tile_at_pixel(x, y):
    """
    Function finds the corresponding tile coordinates of pixel at top left, defaults to (None, None) given a coordinate.

    x -> int; x position of pixel
    y -> int; y position of pixel
    returns tuple (tilex, tiley)
    """
    for tilex in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for tiley in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left, top = left_top_coords_tile(tilex, tiley)
            tile_rect = pygame.Rect(left, top, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            if tile_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (tilex, tiley)
    return (None, None)


def draw_highlight_tile(tilex, tiley):
    """
    Function draws the hovering highlight over the tile.

    tilex -> int; x position of tile
    tiley -> int; y position of tile
    """
    left, top = left_top_coords_tile(tilex, tiley)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, HIGHLIGHTCOLOR,
                    (left, top, TILESIZE, TILESIZE), 4)


def show_help_screen():
    """
    Function display a help screen until any button is pressed.
    """
    line1_surf, line1_rect = make_text_objs('Press a key to return to the game',
                                            BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    line1_rect.topleft = (TEXT_LEFT_POSN, TEXT_HEIGHT)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(line1_surf, line1_rect)

    line2_surf, line2_rect = make_text_objs(
        'This is a battleship puzzle game. Your objective is ' \
        'to sink all the ships in as few', BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    line2_rect.topleft = (TEXT_LEFT_POSN, TEXT_HEIGHT * 3)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(line2_surf, line2_rect)

    line3_surf, line3_rect = make_text_objs('shots as possible. The markers on'\
        ' the edges of the game board tell you how', BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    line3_rect.topleft = (TEXT_LEFT_POSN, TEXT_HEIGHT * 4)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(line3_surf, line3_rect)

    line4_surf, line4_rect = make_text_objs('many ship pieces are in each'\
        ' column and row. To reset your game click on', BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    line4_rect.topleft = (TEXT_LEFT_POSN, TEXT_HEIGHT * 5)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(line4_surf, line4_rect)

    line5_surf, line5_rect = make_text_objs('the "New Game" button.',
        BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    line5_rect.topleft = (TEXT_LEFT_POSN, TEXT_HEIGHT * 6)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(line5_surf, line5_rect)

    while check_for_keypress() == None: #Check if the user has pressed keys, if so go back to the game
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick()


def check_for_keypress():
    """
    Function checks for any key presses by pulling out all KEYDOWN and KEYUP events from queue.

    returns any KEYUP events, otherwise return None
    """
    for event in pygame.event.get([KEYDOWN, KEYUP, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP, MOUSEMOTION]):
        if event.type in (KEYDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEMOTION):
            continue
        return event.key
    return None


def make_text_objs(text, font, color):
    """
    Function creates a text.

    text -> string; content of text
    font -> Font object; face of font
    color -> tuple of color (red, green blue); colour of text
    returns the surface object, rectangle object
    """
    surf = font.render(text, True, color)
    return surf, surf.get_rect()


def show_gameover_screen(shots_fired):
    """
    Function display a gameover screen when the user has successfully shot at every ship pieces.

    shots_fired -> the number of shots taken before game is over
    """
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    titleSurf, titleRect = make_text_objs('Congrats! Puzzle solved in:',
                                            BIGFONT, TEXTSHADOWCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2), int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    titleSurf, titleRect = make_text_objs('Congrats! Puzzle solved in:',
                                            BIGFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) - 3, int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) - 3)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    titleSurf, titleRect = make_text_objs(str(shots_fired) + ' shots',
                                            BIGFONT, TEXTSHADOWCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2), int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 + 50))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    titleSurf, titleRect = make_text_objs(str(shots_fired) + ' shots',
                                            BIGFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) - 3, int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 + 50) - 3)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect = make_text_objs(
        'Press a key to try to beat that score.', BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    pressKeyRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2), int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) + 100)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)

    while check_for_keypress() == None: #Check if the user has pressed keys, if so start a new game
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick()


if __name__ == "__main__": #This calls the game loop
    main()
```

Comment: So under what circumstances do you want to "disappear" something?  Tell us what it does now, and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @Kingsley I want to make two images of different colored buttons. When one button is showing, then it is that players turn, and when that player clicks on a tile then that button disappears and the other button reappears, singling a turn change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there's two ways of doing this.

The more common way is to re-paint the entire screen on each iteration of the main loop.

For example:

```
### Main Loop
while not done:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()               # Location of mouse-click
            player_moves.append ( PlayerMove( mouse_position ) )  # Make a new move

    # Re-paint the screen
    window.fill( OCEAN_BLUE_COLOUR )    # clear the screen
    # Paint each of the players turns
    for m in player_moves:
        m.draw( window )    # paints a hit or miss icon

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Alternatively, instead of re-painting everything, only change the items that have updated, or when events happen.  This is close to the "dirty-rectangles" method of updating.

```
# Initially paint the screen
window.fill( OCEAN_BLUE_COLOUR )    # clear the screen

### Main Loop
while not done:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()      # Location of mouse-click
            move = playerMove( mouse_position )
            move.draw( window )

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The difficulty of the second method, is that the program needs to clean up after the movement of on-screen images (otherwise they will leave a trail).  Obviously in a battleship game, no on-screen elements move - but things like re-drawing scores or starting a new game *will* need to somehow erase the background.   I'm not sure if this will also re-paint the window after it has been occluded by another window.

If you are a beginner programmer, I would use the first method.  It's much simpler, and a lot of games are written this way.

Comment: So there is no “hide” or “show” method in pygame? I know how to make an image transparent - make a transparent color at 0,0,0,0 and make the image that color - maybe is it possible to just return it to its original state before you colored it? Or would it work if I just kept it transparent and .blit it again?

Comment: And @Kingsley if I were to give you my code could you point me to the places where I should add the new code/ what the new code should be?

Comment: @2tmb - It's best to edit your question to include the relevant code.  You could add a `hide()` method to a sprite that swapped the image for a transparent one - but this is more a job-specific change.  It's not very efficient to draw sprites the user can't see, so maybe expand on your reasons for wanting this sort of operation.  Perhaps someone can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I edited my question to include the necessary code; the only problem is that it uses images so on one will really be able to put the code into a program. I want to make it like turn buttons; when green is on, then it is green's turn, and when red is on, it is red's turn. an alternative option is to just highlight one of the options.